Different "types" of Negative Binomial Distribution
From my reading around the subject, there are two types of negative binomial distribution, both of which can be defined as the behaviour of a sequence of Bernoulli trials with probability of success $p$ such that $0 < p < 1$.

1: The total number of trials before the $k$th success.


2: The number of failures occurring before the $k$th success

Both of these types have a variant in which "success" and "failure" are swapped over, which leads to essentially the same formulae but with $p$ replaced with $1 - p$.
The question is: do these have a standard name? How does one refer unambiguously, for example, to a NBD of the first type above, without stating in full its specification?
I did find an obscure site success. which appears to be a forum for students taking actuarial exams, but this is the only reference I can see for "Type 1" and "Type 2" (consistent with the numbering scheme above).
This numbering scheme has been adopted by ProofWiki but apart from that I have not been able to find anything else regarding this.
Can anyone point me towards a source which documents this in detail? (Apart from Wikipedia, which gathers all the threads but does not identify each type by means of a unique name.)
